# How to place a table in a PDF via rmarkdown or format the header text more precisely?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I would like the RMarkdown code below (at the end of the post) to output pages with one of the header options below. The main issue is how to achieve the formatting as I know how to get the date and page numbers.

I have googled for putting tables into the header, but haven't found anything. Formatting the data more precisely is an option too (that is Header Option 2), but I haven't found anything on how to do this. I have played around with formatting but nothing worth putting here that isn't already in the RMarkdown code below.

**Question**: is it possible to implement one of the options below ? And how can it be done.

**Header Option 1: With Table** including text formatting (including the `:` character if possible but that is not absolutely necessary).

[image]

**Header Option 2: Formatted Similarly without the Table** or this can even have a box around it.

[image]

**Code for Creating a Multi Page Example PDF** This is the item I would like to modify the header on to include either the table solution or just the formatted solution without the table.

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example With Numbered Sections"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 6
    number_sections: true
    includes:
        in_header: header.tex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lastpage}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[RO,RE]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{Header Message}
- \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{Footer Messge on the Left}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Footer Messge on the Right}
---

\thispagestyle{fancy}

# Example R Rarkdown : Numbered Sections

## R Markdown

### Description

Some description text

\newpage

#### Details

Details go here.

\newpage

## Plots

Plots go here

\newpage

Last page
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/how-to-insert-a-table-on-the-header

Comment: @Peter thanks, I will look closer at that. The thing that isn’t obvious to me is how to fit that solution into R Markdown YAML

Comment: It is  possible, I've done something very similar, although based on a pdf_documnent rather than the bookdown version. It was a while ago, I've only a basic knowledge of latex and found it rather fiddly and it took a while, but doable, basically you just add the latex code to the markdown document after the yaml header. I don't have time at the moment to look into this in any detail.

Comment: @Peter no worries, what you said about adding it after the YAML header helps. I will see if it works and update this post.

Comment: What you will probably end up with is a load of lines of latex code defining the header table and text where currently you have: `\thispagestyle{fancy}` ; Maybe copy the code from the tex.stackexchange link and work from that code modifying step by step to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Peter This will take some fiddling as I am working through various errors it gives me. One is `! Undefined control sequence.` then followed by `l.93 \makepagestyle` and `{mystyle}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way, no doubt there are others...

1. Create a new fancy header page style
2. Define the table style header (and remove some of the default behaviours)
3. remove the head rule
4. for some reason the first page does not like a header so force the header on the first page with `\thispagestyle(...)`
5. define the subsequent page styles as the tableheader.

Edit appearance as required...

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example With Numbered Sections"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:  
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: true


header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lastpage}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{lipsum}




---


\fancypagestyle{tableHeader}{
    
    \fancyhf{}
    
    \setlength\headheight{90pt}

\fancyhead[C]{
\centering{
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\LARGE{Title}}} \\ 
      \hline
      \textbf{\Large{Field 1:}}  & \textbf{\Large{Field 2:}}  & \textbf{\Large{Date:}}  & \textbf{\Large{Page:}}\\
      \textbf{\Large{Information}}  & \textbf{\Large{Information}}  & \textbf{\Large{`r Sys.Date()`}}  & \textbf{\Large{{\thepage} of \pageref{LastPage}}}\\ 
      \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  }}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\thispagestyle{tableHeader}

\pagestyle{tableHeader}






# Section 1

\lipsum[3]

## sub section 


\newpage

\lipsum[2]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I do wish it was easier to do thing in RMarkdown w/o having to add as much TeX as I have been adding lately, but at least it is a solution.

Comment: A strange thing happens when my toc level is two and the TOC is longer than one page, the header table disappears from the title page but not from any other page. I had to delete and add back sections until I found where it broke. Either having less sections made the problem disappear, or setting the `toc_depth` to 1.

Comment: The other issue I ran into is tables in the content (not header) were sometimes cut off if they are at the end of the page. It seems R Markdown, when one is doing something a bit out of the ordinary, becomes a bit fragile.

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with the document format, where the first page or front page wants to be completely separate from the body of the document. I suspect if you created a separate front page style and started the document with your tabular header on the second page then the toc could run over several pages without loss of the header. Try  in yaml toc: false, and  start the document  (after the fancy header code) with `\newpage \tableofcontents` at the beginning of the document.